# Printing one item from list using readlines() skips to next line while concatenation with string, how to print on same line?

Tags: python, string, terminal, printing

I am simply trying to output a response in the console using print, the snip of code is very simple, although I can't get it to print on the same line. While reading lines is there some sort of hidden \n because the next word is in a new line? How can I fix this.

```
import random

random_line = random.choice(open('wordlist.txt').readlines())
print((random_line)+"This does not appear on same line")
```

This is the output in the Visual Studio Code terminal:

```
f2kd
This does not appear on same line
```

Thanks in advance,
7KMANN

I looked around, I never actually found an answer I tried end="", or sep="" between them, nothing worked it always skipped to the next line

Comment: The lines returned by `readlines()` each have a newline at the end (except possibly the last one).

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense how could I remove the newline

Comment: `random_line.rstrip("\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random_line` ends with a newline. Use `strip()` to remove it.

```
print(print(random_line.strip() + "This appears on the same line")
```

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific as `strip()` works on whitespace as well as newlines and from both ends. I recommend this solution but with `.rstrip("\n")` to just remove newlines from the right.

Comment: Most of the time you don't need to be that specific, since any whitespace will be invisible in the file and should be removed. There may be occasions where leading spaces should be kept, but usually not.